# String interpolation in scala not allowing selecting string from array

Tags: arrays, string, scala, replace

So here is my code block

```
val cols = df.columns
val w = cols(0)
val query1  = s"select $cols(0), square(age) as age, age as age2, first_name, last_name from test"
val query2  = s"select $w, square(age) as age, age as age2, first_name, last_name from test"
```

Query 2 works just fine, query 1 throws the following error

```
no viable alternative at input 'select ['(line 1, pos 7)
== SQL ==
select [Ljava.lang.String;@7988d54(0), square(age) as age, age as age2, first_name, last_name from test
```

Is there anyway to accomplish query1 without creating a temp variable? I want to acces the indexed `cols` datatype directly.

Comment: I addressed your question directly but I just wanted to follow up after reading this again to tell you that if you're doing this as part of a SQL query, you're bypassing the safety of the JDBC driver. You're inviting SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by nesting an expression within the string you're interpolating:

```
s"select ${col(0)} and then..."
s"select ${df.columns(0)} and then..."
```

You use the `${expr}` to hold some `expr` which is valid code. The single variable version of the interpolation phrase `$foo` is actually short hand for `${foo}`.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on the proper way to do this without being vulnerable to injection?  I am using this query with spark, so `df = sqlContext.sql(query)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give you a good recommendation as I have never used the SQL dataframe version. The JDBC drivers use prepared statements but I doubt there is the equivalent in Spark (I could be wrong.) There's probably a question on SO with the answer.